# Spring Security Context is not propagated to the new Thread if using request.startAsync on JBoss AS 7

Tags: spring, spring-security, jboss, jboss7.x

I tried to use async request processing in my Spring and Spring Security based web application running on JBoss AS 7, but the security context is not propagated to the new Thread in my controller.

I used the very same code as described in 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#servletapi-start-runnable

To see the simple reproducer, navigate to https://github.com/trepel/async-request-error

I am using Spring 4.2.1, Spring Security 4.0.2. I tried with other version combinations, but still no luck. However it works on other containers (tested on Tomcat 7, Tomcat 8, and WildFly 10). Unfortunately I need to use JBoss AS 7.

Thanks you for your hints.

Comment: take a look at this https://developer.jboss.org/thread/221106

Comment: thanks @MangEngkus, I tried with EAP 6.4.0.GA (AS 7.5.0.Final-redhat-21) but it doesn't work.